# python - align labels to existing UI

Tags: python, interface

I have this bunch of text labels displaying the final resolutions, i'd like to have it aligned to the existing UI:

[image: UI Preview]

Here's my code so far:

```py
    # UI Drawing
    
    layout = self.layout
    split = layout.split(factor=0.25)
    col1 = split.column(align=True)
    col1.alignment='RIGHT' 
    col2 = split.column(align=True)
    label = self.layout.label
    layout.use_property_split = True
    layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    
    if not scnR.use_border:
        col1.label(text="Final Resolution")
        col2.label(text=" {} x {} px"
            .format(str(int(rezX)),str(int(rezY))))
```

(Please don't mind all the useless variables there, I try lots of different things and clean it once the code is finalized)

Comment: Turns out I could ^^  I knew such addons existed, I just wanted a simple preview of my final resolution without any heavier tasks. And also practice with Blender's API a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I was under deep tunnel vision. The answer was in front of my eyes: changing the split factor to 0.4!

So line 4, going from

```py
split = layout.split(factor=0.25)
```

To:

```py
split = layout.split(factor=0.4)
```

The result is eyeballed, but it seems correct:

[image: corrected UI preview]

And here's the final script if you are interested :

[Blender Final Rez Display - Displays a preview of the final resolutions in Blender, taking the resolution percentage and render border into account. · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/L0Lock/b8fc6202ec38abec1d516ef4c4ee5772)